# MySQL: Select remaining rows

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I've searched everywhere for this, but I can't seem to find a solution. Perhaps I'm using the wrong terms. Either way, I'm turning to good ol' trusty S.O. to help my find the answer.

I have two tables, we'll call them 'tools' and 'installs'

```
tools = id, name, version
installs = id, tool_id, user_id
```

The 'tools' table records available tools, which are then installed by a user and recorded in the 'installs' table. Selecting the installed tools are simple enough:

```
SELECT tools.name
  FROM tools
  LEFT JOIN installs
  ON tools.id = installs.tool_id
  WHERE user_id = 99 ;
```

How do I select the remaining tools -- the ones that have yet to be installed by user #99?

I'm sorry if this is painfully obvious, but I just can't seem to figure it out! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT t.name
     FROM TOOLS t
LEFT JOIN INSTALLS i ON i.tool_id = t.id
                    AND i.user_id = 99
    WHERE i.id IS NULL
```

Alternately, you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM TOOLS t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM INSTALLS i
                   WHERE i.tool_id = t.id
                     AND i.user_id = 99)
```

...or `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT t.name
  FROM TOOLS t
 WHERE t.id NOT IN (SELECT i.tool_id
                      FROM INSTALLS i
                     WHERE i.user_id = 99)
```

Of the three options, the `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` is the most efficient on MySQL.  [You can read more about it in this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).